# Use Regex string to find 2 or more word by group or other means

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, wordnet

Finding for regex string that can optimize a search result from the question bank.
Example:
Question: How do you start a conversation with a friend?

Use -> Regex String

Question Bank-

1. Start a conversation with a friend
2. Build a conversation with my friend
3. Start a dialog with my friend
4. Start a game
5. Conversation is started by saying Hello, person name

Answer -
1, 2, 3. - are the answers
4,5 - are not related

For now, I'm using WordNet to get the nouns and verbs and then querying to find the result.
Is it possible to get search for the question which has at least 2 words found?
Current Regex: `/(?=.*\bstart\b)(?=.*\bconversation\b)(?=.*\bfriend\b).*/gi`
Returns only when all words are found.

Comment: can you prepare a simple code example? I mean, you have this list in an array etc.

Comment: Regex: `/(?=.*\bstart\b)(?=.*\bconversation\b)(?=.*\bfriend\b).*/gi`
------------
Answer:
1. How should I start a conversation about friend
2. How should I initiate a conversation about friend 
---------
From List:
1. How should I start a conversation about a friend
2. How should I initiate a conversation about friend
3. What should I tell my kid when it comes to friend
4. Do girls read other's conversations?
5. asdakjsnjkd asnjkansk kans
6. Do you know about my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be way easier to do it using simple `indexOf`. I think it would be faster as well.

```
const words = [...];
let matchedWord = 0;
for(let word of words){
  if(questionSentence.indexOf(word) > -1) matchedWord+=1
  if(matchedWord > 1) {
    return questionSentence;
  }
}
```

The complexity arises because you need to know if a word is matched or not in the past. I would really not use regex for that. You can even wrap it a function like this:

```
function matchWords(sentence, words, threshold){
    const lowercaseSentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
    let matchedWord = 0;
    for(let word of words){
      if(lowercaseSentence.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          matchedWord+=1
      }
      if(matchedWord >= threshold) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sweet the second code works like magic. but the problem is I need a regex code to search from Mongo DB.

Answer (score 0):

It took some time but I found one answer.
Regex String to search a list of words from a list of sentences:
Note an N threshold is required(meaning the resultant sentence should have N-words or more present in it.)

Regex String:
//For N = 2
`/(word1|word2|word3|)([ -z]*)?(word1|word2|word3)/gi`

//For N = 3
`/(word1|word2|word3|)([ -z]*)?(word1|word2|word3)([ -z]*)(word1|word2|word3)/gi`